# When to use String.subSequence method over String.subString?

Tags: java, string, substring, charsequence, subsequence

I know subSequence returns a charSequence which is a read-only. Also, String class implements CharSequence. subString returns a String.

But, amongst subsequence and substring, when and which one to prefer

Answer (score 3):

From the [API javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> An invocation of this method of the form
>
> ```
>     str.subSequence(begin, end)
> ```
>
> behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
>     str.substring(begin, end)
> ```

And also:

> This method is defined so that the String class can implement the CharSequence interface.

so, it is appropriate to use `subSequence` when you are working with objects of type `CharSequence` rather than `String`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `substring`.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#subSequence-int-int-) says the two have the same behavior.  Although `subSequence` returns a `CharSequence` and `substring` returns a `String`, `String` implements `CharSequence`, thus you can always use `substring` in contexts where a `CharSequence` is required.

According to the javadoc, `subSequence` is there because it has to be, in order to implement a method defined in `CharSequence`.  Since it's there because it's required and not particularly because there's a reason to use it, I don't see any reason to use it if you have a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from `java.util.regex.Pattern.split` where `String.subSequence` will be used if a String is passed as input arg:

```
    public String[] split(CharSequence input, int limit) {
...
                String match = input.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString();
...
```